Setting CSP Headers to Allow Javascript fIles
I'm encountering a problem with something called CSP when trying to execute a Javascript file in my project.
Error message in console:

bootstrapAutofill.ts…oader-R_TAdozE.js:8 Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://d7f89120-b3fb-4edf-a0c6-6aca3e7e7d97/assets/bootstrapAutofill.ts-DSLwOlpR.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.*

The script file is located locally on my computer and inserted via the <script> tag in HTML Header.
I have never seen this error before and can't seem to solve it.
I have no experience with setting HTTP Headers before so any help/guiding on the issue is appreciated.
I have tried using the  tag with no luck either.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried using the <meta> tag to allow CSP for src-script.

here's some documentation for something called CSP - now that you know what it is, you could probably show how you've currently set CSP
